# Mostrar Elemento oculto al marcar un Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo haría para que al marcar cualquiera de los Checkbox aparezca el botón “Eliminar Seleccionados” que está oculto con “display:none”; Y al desmarcarlos todos, se oculte de nuevo el botón.

Y si es posible, que muestre un Alert preguntando si “¿Está seguro de eliminar (Nº de seleccionados) registros?”

Gracias de antemano...!!!

```html
<form name="fmr_1">

<!-- boton oculto -->
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar Seleccionados" style="display:none">
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox">Luis <br>
<input type="checkbox">José <br>
<input type="checkbox">Pedro <br>
<input type="checkbox">Miguel <br>

</form>
```

Comment: esto se puede hacer con Ajax te sugiero que investigues esa tecnologia

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: @Mr.Manutri no creo que Ajax sea necesario en este caso. Yo pondria un evento para todos los inputs con cierta clase y que cuando cambie su estado compruebe cuantos hay marcados para ocultar o no el boton que pide. Un saludo

Comment: Hola... Yo lo hacía con una función jquery dentro de un bucle, a la cual le pasaba el ID de los checkbox en cada vuelta. Pero esto estaba mal hecho, porque la función se repetía en cada vuelta. Como no se mucho de Jquery lo deje así no más. Pero gracias al foro pude conseguir mejorarlo. la próxima comparto el código. Saludos...!!!

Comment: @jose7777 no hace falta que sea la proxima vez. por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir lo que intentaste aunque ya esté resuelta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parte 1 - Comprobar elementos marcados**

Para manipular el estilo de los elementos del DOM jquery nos provee de varias formas de hacerlo.
Todas conllevan modificar la propiedad css que queramos, conllevando el uso directo de una funcion que realiza toda la manipulacion del estilo de forma abstracta con metodos como `show`, `hide` ...

O por otro lado modificando implicitamente las propiedades css que queramos del elemento o elementos en cuestión con el uso del metodo `css` o `attribute`

```js
$(function(){
  $('#modficarImplicitamente').css('display', 'none');
  $('#modficarAbstractamente').hide();
});
```

```css
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#modficarImplicitamente {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
}

#modficarAbstractamente {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modficarImplicitamente">modficarImplicitamente</div>
<div id="modficarAbstractamente">modficarAbstractamente</div>
```

Una vez conociendo esto solo tenemos que ejecutar una funcion cada vez que el usuario haga click en cada check podria ser algo como esto

```js
function tengoQueMostrarBoton() {
  var elementos = $('input.miOpcion');
  var algunoMarcado = elementos.toArray().find(function(elemento) {
     return $(elemento).prop('checked');
  });
  
  if(algunoMarcado) {
    $('#miBoton').show();
  } else {
    $('#miBoton').hide();
  }
}
```

```css
#miBoton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="miOpcion" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="tengoQueMostrarBoton()" /> 
<input class="miOpcion" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="tengoQueMostrarBoton()" /> 
<input class="miOpcion" type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="tengoQueMostrarBoton()" /> 
<input class="miOpcion" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="tengoQueMostrarBoton()" /> 
<input class="miOpcion" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="tengoQueMostrarBoton()" /> 


<button id="miBoton"> hacer algo </button>
```

**Parte 2 - Ejecutar alerta de confirmación**

Para la segunda pregunta que haces la respuesta es si, si se puede hacer, de hecho la funcionalidad del navegador que nos permite hacerlo se llama con la función `confirm`. El resultado de esta función será `true` o `false` y nos servirá para saber la decisión del usuario.

```js
function eliminar() {
  //implmentar logica con Ajax por ejemplo
  alert("Eliminando");
}

function abrirPregunta() {
  var respuesta = confirm("Desea eliminar X elementos?");
  if(respuesta) {
    eliminar();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abrirPregunta()">Eliminar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

He puesto clases a los checkbox y un id al botón para manejarlo de mejor forma. El ejemplo sería así:

```js
var seleccionados = 0

$(".check-nombres").change(function() {
  seleccionados = $(".check-nombres:checked").length
  $("#boton-eliminar").toggle(seleccionados > 0)
})
$("#boton-eliminar").click(function() {
  alert("¿Está seguro de eliminar "+ seleccionados +" registro(s)?")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="fmr_1" onsubmit="return false">

<!-- boton oculto -->
<input type="submit" id="boton-eliminar" value="Eliminar Seleccionados" style="display:none">
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" class="check-nombres">Luis <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-nombres">José <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-nombres">Pedro <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-nombres">Miguel <br>

</form>
```

Comment: Te recuperé la respuesta ya que al final el resto de usuarios no esperó a que el autor la modificara. Buena respuesta. un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
      $('.change').change(function () {
       $('#btn_submit').css("display", "block");
      });
      $('#fmr_1').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //Creo el array que almacenará los valores de los checkbox
        var val = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          //Almaceno los checkbox 'checked', su valor en un array
          val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log('val: ['+val+']');
        if (confirm('¿Está seguro de eliminar '+val.length+ ' registros?') == true) {
          //Envias los datos por ajax ejem...
          return true;
        } else {
          //No hace nada.
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="fmr_1" id="fmr_1">

<!-- boton oculto -->
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar Seleccionados" style="display:none;" id='btn_submit'>
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="luis" class="change">Luis <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="jose" class="change">José <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="pedro" class="change">Pedro <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="miguel" class="change">Miguel <br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera:

**EDIT**

Agregado mensaje de confirmacion

Al código original solo le puse una clase `(boton-oculto)` al botón que esta oculto para poder identificarlo mas fácilmente desde jquery

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
       $(".boton-oculto").show()
    }else{
       $(".boton-oculto").hide()
    }
});

$('form').submit(function( event ) {
   var seleccionados = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
   if(!confirm('¿Está seguro de eliminar '+seleccionados+' registros?') ){
      event.preventDefault();
   } 
});
```

```css
.boton-oculto{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="fmr_1">

<!-- boton oculto -->
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar Seleccionados" class="boton-oculto">
<br><br>

<input type="checkbox">Luis <br>
<input type="checkbox">José <br>
<input type="checkbox">Pedro <br>
<input type="checkbox">Miguel <br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar jquery para poder realizar lo que necesitas. Te dejo un ejemplo, el botón de submit lo cambie por un botón para poder realizar luego el envío del formulario con jquery al hacer la validación los checkboxes. Espero te sirva.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var totalCheckeds = 0;
        $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
            totalCheckeds = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
            if (totalCheckeds > 0) {
                $("input:button").show();
            } else {
                $("input:button").hide();
            }
        });


        $("input:button").click(function() {
            var resp = confirm("Esta seguro de eliminar " + totalCheckeds + " registros?");

            if (resp) {
                $("#fmr_1").submit();
            } 
        });         

});

<form name="fmr_1" id="fmr_1" method="post">

    <!-- boton oculto -->
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar Seleccionados" style="display:none">
    <br><br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="1">Luis <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="2">José <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="3">Pedro <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="4">Miguel <br>

</form>
```